# Java Scanner nextInt() and next()

Tags: java

how do i get numbers by using Scanner

```
Output:
Enter numbers : 1 3 4 5
number # 1 = 1
number # 2 = 3
number # 3 = 4
number # 4 = 5
```

i do not know how to get the numbers to assign each value. it can be 1 to 4 numbers
i know i can use `getInput.nextInt()` 3 times , but i want the numbers i typed match the number of  `getInput.nextInt()`

My code

```
Scanner getInput = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter numbers :");
int number1 = getInput.nextInt();
int number2 = getInput.nextInt();
int number3 = getInput.nextInt();
```

or

```
while(getInput.hasNextInt()){
    number = getInput.nextInt();
     System.out.println(number);
  }
```

it would be infinite loop..

Comment: fail how? if there's an exception stacktrace please post it. otherwise describe how the output differs from your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Use the methods available in the Scanner class to help you out. Like `hasNextInt()`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29

Answer (score 0):

You can use getInput.nextInt() 4 times when there are 4 numbers in line.